# Test multiple boolean variables without multiple if statements

Tags: java

I have a class with only boolean parameters

```
Class Foo{
 boolean a;
 boolean b;
 boolean c;
}
```

Based on what values are  set to true in an object of this class I have to generate a string.
My current approach looks similar to this

```
public String generate(Foo obj){
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

if(obj.a){
sb.append("some string");
}

if(obj.b){
sb.append("another string");
}

if(obj.c){
 sb.append("one more string);
}

return sb.toString();
```

Is there a better and more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Can you use an array/collection instead of individual boolean variables?

Comment: What are the strings (are they unique)? What are the booleans used for? I think your example is overly generified to the point it's difficult to understand the best approach at the moment, since what it solves isn't clear.

Comment: If you want a one-liner you could use the ternary operator : `return (obj.a ? "some string" : "") + (obj.b ? "another string" : "") + (obj.c ? "one more string" : "");` but you're sacrificing readability.

Comment: What about a method that validates the boolean and appends conditionally? ```private testAndAppend(StringBuilder sb, Boolean testBoolean, String appendText) { if(testBoolean) sb.append(appendText); }```. Too much?

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a branch-less approach here (usually by multiplying with booleans), using the ternary operator may be clear:

```
sb += (a == true) ? "some string"     : "";
sb += (b == true) ? "another string"  : "";
sb += (c == true) ? "one more string" : "";
```

Effectively, this is the same as an if-else block, just more organized and people are more comfortable with this being in a single line for the expression.

**Ternary Operator usage:**
The beginning is <variable> <operator>.
The next section is ( <condition> ) ? where the question mark asks "is this true?".
Then the first item is a valid value for the variable at the start followed by ":".
Finally the last item is the value if the condition is false.